# Dropbox closes on Hibernation

Tags: windows-10, dropbox, hibernate

I am running Windows 10 Professional 64-bit with Bitlocker applied.

When I leave my laptop I put it into Hibernate mode for security purposes.

Unfortunately, however, when I awaken my laptop from its hibernated state, then Dropbox invariably closes. (Or perhaps it closes when going into hibernate state)

All my other programs (e.g. Chrome, IE, Office) remain exactly as they were before the Hibernation. It is only Dropbox that seems to be affected.

Furthermore, the icon on the taskbar (near the clock) remains and does not disappear unless I hover my mouse over it. Because it does not disappear, I can very easily forget and then assume that my files are syncing, and often my colleagues who have relied on a file being synchronized do not get the latest updates.

I have reinstalled Dropbox and this did not help

Comment: If the tray icon remains until you mouse over it, that suggests Dropbox has crashed (at least has not closed in a controlled way). Is it the latest version of Dropbox? Do you have any firewall and/or VPN software installed? This may give you some ideas: https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/Missing-files-and-folders/Dropbox-stuck-quot-connecting-quot-after-recovering-from/m-p/37457

Comment: @Joe P. It is the latest version of dropbox. There is eSet AV installed and Windows Firewall.  Thanks for the link...

Answer (score 1):

I'll show you how you could get this to work. Firstly we'll make a .bat after this we will make windows open it every time you logon your pc.

Making a autoopendropbox.bat file.

1. Firstly open notepad
2. Copy and paste the following:
   start YOUR LOCATION TO DROPBOX
3. Replace your location to dropbox with the location on your pc. (if you dont know, just rightclick on the icon, on your desktop, after this choose "open file location")
4. It should look something like this
   C:\programs\dropbox
5. Now open "task scheduler"
6. In here choose "create task"
7. Choose "tiggers"
8. Choose "New"
9. Press "on a schedule" and change it to "at logon"
10. Press "ok"
11. Press "action"
12. Press "new"
13. Now find you script
14. press "ok" a few times so you make it.

Now each time you logon you should see dropbox starting.

Disclaimer: it might not be 100% how to do it, as im from Denmark, so I have translated a lot of text.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion! Although your workaround would work - and in fact I employ such methods on my servers where Dropbox seems to quit on a fairly regular basis  - I was looking to understand *why* Dropbox was closing and how to prevent it closing, rather than *how* to resurrect it if it fell.